# Javascript 2014-08-19

Tags: javascript, date

Does anyone know why the day 08/19/2014 in Javascript return the day 08/18/2014?

```
> new Date(2014, 9, 18)
Sat Oct 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
> new Date(2014, 9, 19)
Sat Oct 18 2014 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
> new Date(2014, 9, 20)
Mon Oct 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)
```

Comment: Working fine!! http://jsfiddle.net/jy5Hb/

Comment: I don't see the problem, unless you're asking why month 9 returns October. That's because months start with 0 = January.

Comment: Could it have to do with BRT vs BRST?

Comment: It's got to be the daylight savings time transition. [BRT](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/sa/brt.html) vs [BRST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/sa/brst.html) Notice that the offset changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date(2014, 9, 19)` technically *[does not exist in parts of Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=45)*. First, note `Date()` returns not just a date, but a date *and* time. The time defaulted to midnight because it was not explicitly passed. However, daylights saving time means midnight Oct 19 2014 is skipped. (Oct 18 23:59:59 is followed by Oct 19 **1:00:00**)

I guess JavaScript tried to convert this non-existent date-time into a valid date-time that actually exists. If you are just interested in the date, a work-around might be to explicitly pass the hour parameter like this:

```
> new Date(2014, 9, 19, 12)
```

Comment: Yes.This is the Brazilian summer schedule, when the clock will late in one hour. 0 hours of 19/08 are 23:00 of 18/08.
Thank you!